# how to handle null or empty json key value response in retrofit 2 response body?

Tags: android, retrofit2

I am using retrofit 2 in android. My app crashes when one of the  value return null **key like  "TOTAL_EXPENSE_AMOUNT": null**. My json is like below:

```
[{
    "YEAR": "2019",
    "TOTAL_AMOUNT": "1580292",
    "TOTAL_EXPENSE_AMOUNT": "1740857",
    "TOTAL_BALANCE": "-160565"
},
 {
    "YEAR": "2018",
    "TOTAL_AMOUNT": "144000",
    "TOTAL_EXPENSE_AMOUNT": null,
    "TOTAL_BALANCE": null
 } ]
```

**1.**.My retrofit Interface is below:

```
public interface Api {

@POST("User/yearly_balance_expense_list.php")
Call<List<Balance_Data_Model>> getBalanceList();

}
```

**2.** My api service is bellow like :

```
public class ApiService {

public static final String BASE_URL = IPConfigure.getIP();
Api api = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build().create(Api.class);


  public Call<List<Balance_Data_Model>> getBalanceList(){
    return api.getBalanceList();
    }

 }
```

**3.**My projo file is below :

```
public class Balance_Data_Model {

@SerializedName("YEAR")
@Expose
public String year = "";

@SerializedName("TOTAL_AMOUNT")
@Expose
public String total_amount = "";


@SerializedName("TOTAL_EXPENSE_AMOUNT")
@Expose
public String total_expense = "";

@SerializedName("TOTAL_BALANCE")
@Expose
public String total_balance = "";

//getter/setter here

}
```

**4.**I have used below code from activity

```
ApiService apiService = new ApiService();
    Call<List<Balance_Data_Model>> call = apiService.getBalanceList();
    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Balance_Data_Model>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<Balance_Data_Model>> list, Response<List<Balance_Data_Model>> response) {
            Log.e("success--->","success");
            for(Balance_Data_Model m : response.body()){                   
                Log.e("total_expense--->",m.total_expense);
                Log.e("total_balance--->",m.total_balance);
                
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<Balance_Data_Model>> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.e("failure--->",t.toString());
        }
    });
```

First loop it ok. when total_balance is null then app crashes. How to handle it?

Comment: is it the crash error pointed to  `Log.e("total_expense--->",m.total_expense);` ?

Comment: @JohnJoe yes when it Log.e("total_expense--->",m.total_expense); in second iteration of the loop app is crash

Comment: any update for this?

Answer (score 0):

It explained [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log):

[image]

So the proper way to handle this issue is using `if-else`.

```
 if(m.total_expense!=null)
 Log.e("total_expense--->",m.total_expense);
```

Answer (score 0):

the Log is not print null value , it gives exception , if you want to print the log then use below

```
   Log.e("total_expense--->",m.total_expense + "");
```

or you can check m.total_expense!=null then print without "".

Answer (score 0):

Please handle all values from response, It is good.

```
if(response.body() != null){
  for(Balance_Data_Model m : response.body()){
     if(m.total_expense != null)
        Log.e("total_expense--->",m.total_expense);

     if(m.total_balance != null)
        Log.e("total_balance--->",m.total_balance);
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can create a method for check the null value

```
public String amount (String json){

  if(json == null){

     return "";
  else{
    retrun json;
   }


   use like this `String amount=amount(responce.body().getAmount())`
```